# Bound states in 1D & 2D

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

Why does Mother Nature allow bound states in arbitrarily weak attractive potential in 2D but not in 3D?

See, for example, [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.1532538) article, [arXiv:math-ph/0208011](http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0208011).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143630/2451

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on what you mean when you ask *Why?* here? Are you asking what step of the proof breaks down in higher dimensions? Or are you asking if there are no-go theorems forbidding such bound states in higher dimensions? Or something else?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Sure. I'll address your questions one by one. First, I haven't seen a mathematical proof that the statement does not hold in 3D, so it would be great to see such a proof and particularly how it breaks down in higher dimensions. Second, I'm not aware of any such theorems, so it would also be very exciting to know. Third, is there an intuitive explanation, for example, why would higher dimensionality impairs that ability of space to support the bound states?

Comment: @ACuriousMind When I asked this question, I was hoping to see an answer to the third aspect -- intuitive reasoning of the underlying physics.

Comment: One should probably point out, "mother nature" does not "allow" for arbitrary potentials. This is just mathematicians playing with equations of motion that happen to describe real physical systems for CERTAIN choices of potentials. While the results are interesting, even to physicists, they have very, very little in common with actual physics.

Comment: It is explained [here](http://books.google.fr/books?id=oQTnAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA159&lpg=PA159&dq=arbitrarily+weak+attractive+potential+in+3D&source=bl&ots=klEdfXmhOA&sig=fV5shYewRv7QtoU0iHU6TMUyb6c&hl=en&sa=X&ei=t44FVNX-K8LWaJWGgsAD&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=arbitrarily%20weak%20attractive%20potential%20in%203D&f=false)  (pages $159,160$), at least for a simple potential $U(r)= - u \delta(r)$