# How to compute minimum shallowness of quantum well to have at least one bound state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation, potential, ground-state

Given a potential $V$, how does one compute how shallow the potential can be such that it allows at least one bound state?

Comment: For one and two dimension, it always have a bound state. For 3D, this is not true. See: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143630/

Comment: The issue is covered in the article ["finite potential well"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well)

Comment: To reopen this post (v1) consider to be more specific.