# Spatial “wiggliness” of the Schrödinger wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

I am having trouble understanding what the term 'spatial wiggliness' of the Schrodinger wavefunction.

I knows it is related to the kinetic energy of the particle and is associated with the de Broglie relation. A higher local kinetic energy leads to higher degree of spatial wiggliness.

Comment: When you draw wavefunctions (for, say, a particle in an infinite 1D square well), don’t the higher-energy ones look wigglier to you?

Comment: A formal definition of Wiggliness is the number of zeros in a suitable axis maximizing their number, so, effectively, a number of periods, so effective frequency. There are theorems proving the energy associated with them is a monotonic function of this wiggliness.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/295857/when-does-the-nth-bound-state-of-a-1d-quantum-potential-have-n-maxima-minima).