# How can theories about 1D or 2D systems be generalized for 3D systems?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

I was watching a lecture video from [MITx](https://youtu.be/ERe1y5hgM2o) $^\dagger$ by professor Barton Zwiebach. He proved a pretty cool theorem "every attractive 1-dimensional potential has a bound state"; however, that only holds in *1-dimension*, and the theorem doesn't hold  in 3-dimension.

Then I was left wondering:

How do we generate any results only valid in 1D/2D to our 3D world (I mean, after all, our world is 3D) ? Or how this theorem predicts anything in our real world such that we can test it experimentally?

I am a total newbie in experiment, if this question sounds silly to you, I am sorry!

---

I was thinking if an electron being constraint on a very thin plate would work. But I am not so sure, say, what about a curved - but super thin - plate? Does it counts 1D? or 3D?

$\dagger$: The course's website [here](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:MITx+8.05.1x+1T2018/course/). Which requires you have a EdX ID(free) to view the material.

Comment: Related: [Why the statement “there exist at least one bound state for negative/attractive potential” doesn't hold for 3D case?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143630/2451)

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking here: A theorem about 1D doesn't predict anything about the real world. Why do you think it does?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I wonder if there is any experimental means to test this theorem, after all, physics is experimental science. (furthermore, I was thinking if we can achieve that experiment with help of (constraint) nearly infinite potential wall .)

Comment: at 1st that idea sounds quite reason (at least to me), but later I get confused: considering a "curved" but yet super thin (say ~ electron size) plate, does the theorem still work or not?

Comment: [Navier–Stokes existence and smoothness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_existence_and_smoothness), which is a [_Millennium Prize_ problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_Prize_Problems#Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_existence_and_smoothness), has been solved in 2-dimensions since the 1960's.  A 3-D result hasn't yet been reported despite its publicity.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but could [quantum wells](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_well) or [quantum wires](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_wire) be similar to what you are looking for?