# Bound State of Square Potential in $d$-dimension

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

I'm trying to find, How does the number of bound state change as we change the dimension of space?

In 1 & 2 dimension, finite square well we know that there always exists a bound state, as shown [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143630/247238). For higher dimensions, it's easy to see that, For a given value of $V_0$ (depth of the well), the number of bound states decreases. Considering this to be in general, that dimension $d$ is increasing. How I can show that this will always be true?

In $d$ dimension, there are $d$ direction, say $x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_d$ so that SE given by
$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\psi(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_d)+V(x_1,x_2,\ldots ,x_d)\psi(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_d)=E\psi(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_d),
$$
where potential is $-V_0$ if $x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots +x_d^2\leq a^2$ else $0$. I'm clueless, How to start? Any hint is appreciable.

Comment: You should start by writing the Schrodinger equation in the spherical coordinate, reducing to the problem to a one-dimensional one in the radial direction.

Comment: @MengCheng But it's d dimensions, Spherical coordinates are for three dimensions only.

Comment: What I mean is the generalization of spherical coordinate in d dimensions.